# How to have Excel return column and row headings based on / alongside an ordered list of values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

A measurement of ion transport numbers went wrong when an unorthodox concentration was accidentally used. An analysis of what could have happened yielded the following table. The values  have been edited for simplification but conform to the original mix.

[image: What I currently have]

I wish to order all of these numbers from biggest to smallest in a separate table. The row and column headings (numbers from 1 to 6) are also required. The end result should look like this:

[image: WhatINeed]

- What would be a method to achieve the outcome? The less effort the better :-); the dimensions of the first table and values therein might vary, hence doing the second table by hand is a nightmare.
- Here is a link to the file for testing purposes: [archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171020182512/https://fv6.failiem.lv/down.php?i=z55222nn&n=Testing.xlsx&PHPSESSID=f2oqsf8adsnj09u1mg21jugjj3).

(Currently using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus version 1705 (8201.2193) with Windows 8.1 Professional.)

Comment: Will there ever be duplicate values?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, it is possible (depends on activities of molecular entities in Nernst equation). What difference would this make if I may ask? Does it complicate the ordering in some way?

Comment: It makes the formulas to return the row and column much more complex.

Comment: Simple solution: for the Values column, just have a cell reference to the original table, one table column after another.  The location column is =ROW(cellref)&"-"&COL(cellref), where cellref if the same cell referenced in the value column.  That will replicate for a table column, then edit the reference for the next table column.  Then sort your list and hide or discard the non-numeric values.  It's a few quick, mindless steps.

Comment: Your numbers have 15 signigicant digits, you sure you will have duplicates, seems unlikely.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I was just about to comment. Technically, the numbers here have no real meaning beyond the second decimal point. In this current case (the first table is actually also calculated), there shouldn't be overlap. But future data may be with three significant figures only, hence increasing the likelihood.

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay, rethinking this overlap may be avoided. If my data has three significant figures, I could add some decimal points to each to make them differ but not change the outcome, really (with a randbetween column)

Comment: If you are up for learning play with the DATA> From Table/Range... This used to be PowerQuery but is baked into newer versions of excel. It has an unpivot command that should do the trick.